# How to take advantage of calcite-server

Tags: apache-calcite

Our project relies on calcite-core, but we also need to use DDL statements. The server module (calcite-server) adds DDL support to Calcite. How can we take advantage of calcite-server to support our demands?

[calcite's documentations](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html) have mentioned that

> If you are the author of a sub-project, it is unlikely that your syntax extensions match those in calcite-server, so we recommend that you add your SQL syntax extensions by extending the core parser; if you want DDL commands, you may be able to copy-paste from calcite-server into your project.

Does this mean that we should extend Calcite-core by ourselves instead of using Calcite-server directly. 
Is there a better way?

Comment: If you are fine using the dialect of DDL supported by `calcite-server`, feel free. But if you have your own dialect of DDL, you'll likely need to write your own version of `calcite-server`.

Comment: If this answered your question, I can post this as an answer for you to accept so this question can be resolved.

Comment: ok，thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine using the dialect of DDL supported by `calcite-server`, feel free. But if you have your own dialect of DDL, you'll likely need to write your own version of `calcite-server`.